# Netlogo - start plotting at tick 1

Tags: plot, netlogo

I need to say to the plots to start at tick 1 or at least after the setup is done.
This because i have some variable that at the beginning are set to 0 and the plot complains that it cannot divide by 0 (need to plot the ratio between to variables).
I'd like to do this without using that command plot in the code but just in the plots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can usually avoid those situations by calling only calling [`reset-ticks`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#reset-ticks) at the end of you `setup` procedure.

But if you really need the plots to update conditionally, you can do that directly in the plot pen update commands:

[image: pen update commands]

Comment: Recommendation to call `reset-ticks` at the end of `setup`, firmly seconded. All of NetLogo's Sample Models follow this pattern.